# how to get values as per mixed attribute column set for products in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-structures, database-design

I have been struggling to get the desired output from the mysql db. First Please take a look at my table structure

[image: sql table structure]

EDIT: HERE IS MY SCHEMA
http://rextester.com/edit/NNCZ7986

Now when i run the below mentioned query, i get the results as below

```
Select a.prodid,a.product,b.catid,b.category,d.attvalue,c.qty,c.price 
from tbl_products a left join
     tbl_categories b
     on a.catid = b.catid left join
     tbl_prodattval c
     on a.prodid = c.prodid left join
     tbl_attvalues d
     on c.attvalid = d.attvalid
```

Here is the result i get

[image: query result]

product K1 which is in green shows right qty and price
and also shows as a separate row
product K1 which is XL with its qty and price

But, i need product K1 which is in green + also XL (Mixed multi attributes) to get the price and quantity

Similarly Tee1 with XL and Green should have 1 qty and price
and Tee1 with XXL with Green should have another

I want results like below (attvalue2 and attvalue3 columns are just imaginary... just to show i want to have product listing from multi attribute)

```
Prodid | Product | catid | category | attvalue | attvalue2 | attvalue3 | qty | price
20 | Tee1 | 14 | Tees | Green | XL |  | 2 | 23.00
20 | Tee1 | 14 | Tees | Blue | XL |  | 2 | 21.00
```

How do i get it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want to achieve.

Comment: And maybe see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Select a.prodid,a.product,b.catid,b.category,d.attID,d.attvalue,c.qty,c.price 
from tbl_products a left join
     tbl_categories b
     on a.catid = b.catid left join
     tbl_prodattval c
     on a.prodid = c.prodid left join
     tbl_attvalues d
     on c.attvalid = d.attvalid.       //can we please see the reults including d.attID value?

Comment: Are color and size the only two attributes and what are their id's?

Comment: sqlfilldle says request content too large (>8000) to build schema... so how do i share the sql schema with data with you guys... please bear with me as i am a newbie

Comment: I have edited the question to put the schema link there (rexter link). hope it helps you to provide me with your valuable answer / guidance

Comment: Your sample data doesn't support the question well. On your screenshot the row (K1, XL) has the price 16 and (K1, green) hast the price 14. That means the two rows come from different rows in table `tbl_prodattval`. And thus you can't combine them into a single row. In your rexester sample you don't even insert price and qty.

Comment: alright, so how do i achieve the results desired... what changes do i need to make in schema... can u pls suggest / guide... thx

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? If so, please give me the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Select a.prodid,a.product,b.catid,b.category,d.attvalue, e.attvalue,c.qty,c.price 
        from tbl_products a 
    left join tbl_categories b
            on a.catid = b.catid 
    left join tbl_prodattval c
            on a.prodid = c.prodid
    left join tbl_attvalues d
           on c.attvalid = d.attvalid
           and d.attID = //in tbl_attributes what is attid for color (ID for color)
     left join tbl_attvalues e
        on c.attvalidid = e.attvalid
          and d.attID =  //'in tbl_attributes what is attid for size (ID for size)
```

Comment: My attributes are dynamic there are multiple products like Apparels, Electronics, Furniture, etc. so its not just size and color.... there are many more attributes but products are being set to attributes as per their type. However as of now the results showing are one attribute, qty, price for product whereas what i need is product from multi attributes to have one qty and price .... like Tee1 (green + XL size) will be $10 with 3 qty .... Tee1 (green + XXL) will be $11 with 5 qty.... Door 1 (Textured + PlasticMaterial + White) will be $59 with 2 qty and so on.